# SSRS: Need to get total numbers of calls which are less than 10 seconds

Tags: reporting-services, count, sum, expression

Looking to get total numbers of calls which are less than 10 second . i have tried these SSRS expression . but result is not accurate.

```
=SUM(IIF(DatePart( "s" ,Fields!call_dur.Value)  <= 10, 1,0)
```

Please help me on this

Call_Dur
---------|
00:00:05

```
=SUM(IIF(DatePart( "s" ,Fields!call_dur.Value)  <= 10, 1,0)
```

Comment: what data type is the call_dur column in your database?

Comment: data type is nchar(20)